# Concept: invocable with unknown arguments

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I've got the following struct `Bar` that requires a `Policy` I want to check with concept

```cpp
template<typename Policy, typename T>
concept FooConcept = requires(std::array<T, 42> arr, size_t val) {
    { Policy::Foo(arr, val, val) } -> std::same_as<T&>;
};

template<typename T, typename Policy>
requires FooConcept<Policy, T>
struct Bar
{
    std::array<T, 42> arr;
    template<typename... Args>
    T& foo(Args... args) {
        return Policy::Foo(arr, args...);
    }
};
```

So the policy that satisfies the `FooConcept` looks like:

```cpp
struct Policy1
{
    template<typename Cont>
    static decltype(auto) Foo(Cont& c, size_t arg1, size_t arg2) {
        ... // do smth with c, arg1, and arg2
    }
};
```

However, according to the logic, each policy with method `Foo` that takes the container and **any number** of size_t and returns `T&` should satisfies `FooConcept`. The Policy that is suitable too but do not get through the FooConcept is:

```
struct Policy2
{
    template<typename Cont>
    static decltype(auto) Foo(Cont& c, size_t arg1, size_t arg2, size_t arg3) {
        ... // do smth with c, arg1, arg2, and arg3
    }
};
```

Use case of the `Bar` here:

```
using MyFancyBar = Bar<int, Policy1, 16>;
// using MyCoolBar = Bar<int, Policy2, 16>;

int main()
{
    MyFancyBar bar;
    // MyCoolBar bar2;
    std::cout << bar.foo(0, 0);
    // std::cout << bar2.foo(0, 1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is whether it is possible to write a concept that takes the function with
**any** numbers of arguments of type size_t or not?

**UPD:** possible solution to my problem is:

```
template<typename Policy, typename T>
concept FooConcept = requires(std::array<T, 42> arr, size_t val) {
    { Policy::Foo(arr, val) } -> std::same_as<T&>;
} or requires(std::array<T, 42> arr, size_t val) {
    { Policy::Foo(arr, val, val) } -> std::same_as<T&>;
} or requires(std::array<T, 42> arr, size_t val) {
    { Policy::Foo(arr, val, val, val) } -> std::same_as<T&>;
} or // ... until I get bored
```

but is there any 'beautiful' solution? [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/dT598Y9Ms)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean "according to the logic, each policy with method `Foo` that takes the container and any number of size_t [...]"? Any number? Like, `Policy1` is not a valid policy because it only takes 2 `size_t`s, or `Policy1` is a valid policy because there exists a number of size_ts that it can take?

Comment: I mean that all Policies with function prototypes should satisfy the FooConcept too:
`static decltype(auto) Foo(Cont& c, size_t arg1, size_t arg2)`, `static decltype(auto) Foo(Cont& c, size_t arg1, size_t arg2, size_t arg3)`, `static decltype(auto) Foo(Cont& c, size_t arg1, size_t arg2, soze_t arg4, ... size_t argN)`

Comment: @falsekeel: Why is that a thing you need? Like, at the place where you're calling this "policy", don't you know how many arguments you're going to pass? You cannot write an expression containing "any number" of arguments; an expression only has a *known* number of arguments. I feel like there's an XY problem happening here.

Comment: what do you mean 'XY problem'?
no, I do know the argument number at the moment of writing policies. I do not know the number of arguments writing the concept

Comment: @falsekeel: "*I do know the argument number at the moment of writing policies.*" I didn't say "at the moment of writing policies"; I was talking about at the moment you are *invoking* the function. Concepts exist to protect template code. Concepts guard expressions; what expression are you trying to use with this template type?

Comment: as I see your point it is `Bar::foo` function.

Comment: Best I got was: `template<typename Policy, typename T,class...TT>
concept FooConcept2 = requires(std::array<T, 42> arr,TT... val) {
    { Policy::Foo(arr, val...) } -> std::same_as<T&>;
};` But you need to specyfy the TT in Policy1

Comment: @falsekeel: "*it is Bar::foo function*" That's not what I asked. I asked about the expression you're using to *call it*. Where do the arguments come from? Why does it uses N numbers of arguments instead of M, and where is that determination made? Concepts are built based on the code you use to talk to those objects. Also, your "policy" only says that the object must accept a particular number of parameters but you don't care how many. But the code calling that "policy" *does* care how many, because it's going to provide a *particular* number. Your concept doesn't protect anything.

Comment: @falsekeel: [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is the thing that prompted you to create such a concept? Can that problem not be solved in a different way?

Comment: please be sure it is not XY problem. OK, OK it is XY problem in terms of architecture of my application, but more than 90% of questions here might be boiled down to it :)

Comment: Of course you're sure your approach is justified, otherwise you wouldn't be asking this. :P NicolBolas's point is that it might not be the case. Writing such concept would require a way to get the suitable *number* of arguments, given the callable. It's possible if the callable doesn't have a templated or overloaded `operator()`, which is not always the case. But normally you wouldn't want to check this in the first place, as others already said.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit long but works. Note that I made changes to your policies too. (The class itself is the template not the function.) You might have to add some `std::remove_reference` to it and I'm not sure you always want to return `C::value_type`, so you will need to improve it if you want to use my code.

The base idea is to build up step by step. First we need to decide if all parameters in a pack are `size_t` (`all_s_con`) then we need to see if a function meets the `R(C,size_t,size_t...)` signature where `R` is the wanted return type and `C` is the container. (`fun_all_s`) Finlay we need to see if `Policy::foo` satisfies that condition (`FooConcept`)

I'm sure there is a better way, but this is the best I got:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <array>
#include <functional>
using std::size_t;

template <class... Args>
struct all_s:std::false_type{};

template <>
struct all_s<size_t>:std::true_type{};

template <class... Args>
struct all_s<size_t,Args...>:all_s<Args...>{};
template <class... Args>
concept all_s_con=all_s<Args...>::value;

template<class C,class R,class Fun>
struct fun_all_s:std::false_type{};
template<class C,class R, class... Args>
requires all_s_con<Args...>
struct fun_all_s<C,R,R(C&,Args...)>:std::true_type{};

template<class C, typename Policy>
concept FooConcept= fun_all_s<C,typename C::value_type,decltype(Policy::foo)>::value;
```

And to use it:

```
template<typename Cont>
struct Policy1
{
    static decltype(auto) foo(Cont& c, size_t arg1, size_t arg2) {
        //... // do smth with c, arg1, and arg2
        return 0;
    }
};

template<typename C, typename Policy>
requires FooConcept<C,Policy>
struct Bar
{
    C arr;
    template<typename... Args>
    C::value_type& foo(Args... args) {
        return Policy::foo(arr, args...);
    }
};
template<typename Cont>
struct Policy2
{
    static decltype(auto) foo(Cont& c, size_t arg1, size_t arg2, size_t arg3) {
        return 0; // do smth with c, arg1, arg2, and arg3
    }
};

using MyFancyBar = Bar<std::array<int,42>, Policy1<std::array<int,42>>>;
```

feel free to try it out:
https://godbolt.org/z/bbYbfrTsa